# How to re-init kartik-v editable rendered via ajax

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I have set up a controller to renderAjax() and JS function to load() into a modal.
The problem occured upon re-opening the modal. 
I've searched through the issues in kartik-v github and he said that the Editable plugin needs to be reinitialized. Also he mentioned about a destroy() function.

How should I do it?